# What does 0x0F mean? And what does this code mean?

Tags: javascript

I have this code. Please make me understand what does this code actually mean

```
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
  {
    x = input.charCodeAt(i);
    output += hex_tab.charAt((x >>> 4) & 0x0F)
           +  hex_tab.charAt( x        & 0x0F);
  }
```

What is 0x0F? And, >>> Mean?

Comment: `0x0f` is a hexadecimal representation of a byte. Specifically, the bit pattern `00001111`

Comment: Okay, And how does that expression make it work there? how does that '(x >>> 4) & 0x0F' return the integer value, as chatAt() function require integer input

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`>>>` is the unsigned bitwise right-shift operator. `0x0F` is a hexadecimal number which equals 15 in decimal. It represents the lower four bits and translates the the bit-pattern `0000 1111`. `&` is a bitwise `AND` operation.

`(x >>> 4) & 0x0F` gives you the upper nibble of a byte. So if you have `6A`, you basically end up with `06`:

```
6A = ((0110 1010 >>> 4) & 0x0F) = (0000 0110 & 0x0F) = (0000 0110 & 0000 1111) = 0000 0110 = 06
```

`x & 0x0F` gives you the lower nibble of the byte. So if you have `6A`, you end up with `0A`.

```
6A = (0110 1010 & 0x0F) = (0110 1010 & 0000 1111) = 0000 1010 = 0A
```

From what I can tell, it looks like it is summing up the values of the individual nibbles of all characters in a string, perhaps to create a checksum of some sort.

Answer (score 5):

`0x0f` is a hexadecimal representation of a byte. Specifically, the bit pattern `00001111`

It's taking the value of the character, shifting it 4 places to the right (`>>> 4`, it's an [unsigned shift](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=60)) and then performing a bit-wise `AND` with the pattern above - eg ignoring the left-most 4 bits resulting in a number 0-15.

Then it adds that number to the original character's right-most 4 bits (the 2nd `& 0x0F` without a shift), another 0-15 number.

Comment: Okay, Can you please give the same code converting to PHP. I am having lots of problem converting that to PHP. How do I do the same process in PHP?

Comment: All the operations can be done the same way in PHP. [See here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) for the syntax

Comment: Careful `>>>` isn't a simple right shift. It's an unsigned right shift and so it ignores the sign bit.

Comment: @VivinPaliath True - but then it ignores the left-most 4 bits... I should clarify though

Comment: @Basic Correct, in this particular case you could use the signed right shift operator and you would get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

`0x0F` is a number in hexadecimal. And `>>>` is the bitwise right-shift operator.